# Active Directory (DNS) BPA: Interface should register its IP addresses in DNS with Server Core

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2019, best-practices, windows-server-core

How to solve the following compliance error message when using the Best Practices Analyzer with DNS running on Windows Server Core?

```
Problem:
The interface Ethernet 2 is not configured to register its addresses in DNS.

Impact:
IP addresses on the interface will not be automatically registered in DNS.

Resolution:
Configure the interface Ethernet 2 to register the connection's addresses in DNS.

Scan time: 8/19/2021 7:15:30 PM

BPA model version: 2.0
```

Since I'm running AD:DS with DNS on Windows Server Core, I don't have the interface to add the option to satisfy this requirement from BPA.

Server is already configured with static IPv4 addresses and DNS:

```
--------------------------------
    Network settings
--------------------------------


Available Network Adapters

Index#  IP address      Description

  2     172.21.1.2      Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #2

Select Network Adapter Index# (Blank=Cancel):  2

--------------------------------
    Network Adapter Settings
--------------------------------


NIC Index               2
Description             Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #2
IP Address              172.21.1.2      fe80::a998:99df:545e:95a3
Subnet Mask             255.255.255.0
DHCP enabled            False
Default Gateway         172.21.1.1
Preferred DNS Server    172.21.1.3
Alternate DNS Server    127.0.0.1
```

Thanks.

PS: I know that I can just ignore it, but ignoring it defeats the purpose of the question.

**EDIT:** There's only one network interface on the server:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet 2                Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #2            4 Up           56-6F-90-D5-00-2A        10 Gbps
```

Comment: No that is for adapter #4. If the host does not have an adapter #4, there may be ghost network connections in the registry/device control panel that can be removed.

Comment: @GregAskew Sorry, I'm an idiot. I copied the message from DC1 and the network config from DC2. I've fixed, numbers match now.

Comment: Ok, the next question is it configured (box checked) to register in DNS?

Comment: That's the problem. @GregAskew. I'm running WS Core. There's no GUI element.

Comment: Oh right (Sorry I don't with with core much)! Well, there may be some PowerShell or netsh command not sure. But if the DC is record is registered in DNS this is probably a non-issue. DC's are fairly aggressive about managing (creating/removing) their DNS records regardless of the network adapter setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell for that:

```
Set-DnsClient -InterfaceIndex 2 -RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $true
```

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/set-dnsclient

Comment: It's already true. But UseSuffixWhenRegistering is false. May this be the issue?

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão I am not sure what BPA is checking exactly. But it will not hurt to set UseSuffixWhenRegistering to $true and find out :) Also, do you mind adding the result of this command to your main post: Get-DnsClient -InterfaceIndex 2 | FL

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue, tried UseSuffixWhenRegistering $true but no go either. Savage.

BPA says:
DNS: Interface Ethernet 2 on the DNS server should be configured to register its IP addresses in DNS.   Configuration

```
Get-DnsClient -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet 2' | Format-List

InterfaceAlias                     : Ethernet 2
InterfaceIndex                     : 5
ConnectionSpecificSuffix           :
ConnectionSpecificSuffixSearchList : {}
RegisterThisConnectionsAddress     : True
UseSuffixWhenRegistering           : False
```

Comment: Ok, so i resolved this by toggle the RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $false, and then back to $true.